# how many smaller circles(radius is equal) I can fit within a larger circle

Tags: geometry, packing-problem

then the question is,the larger radius D,the small radius d,get the largest number of small circle put in the larger?

Comment: See [this](http://www.jstor.org/pss/2688509) and [this](http://www2.stetson.edu/~efriedma/cirincir/).

Comment: See also [Circle packing in a circle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing_in_a_circle).

Comment: I believe this is still an open problem.

Comment: @J. M. isn't: link for that page in Erich Friedman's Packing Center is now https://erich-friedman.github.io/packing/cirincir

Answer (score -3):

The answer can be closely approximated by this equation:

Number of Circles $= 0.83\frac{R_2^2}{r_1^2} - 1.9$  (rounded down to whole number)

where: $R_2$ = radius of larger circle
       $r_1$ = radius of smaller circle

Comment: I made some edits to the typesetting. Please check that I've left the meaning the same.

Comment: I'm skeptical of the result particularly for $R\gg r$; at that point you should be able to get arbitrarily close to the $\pi/\sqrt{12}\approx 0.9$ density of the full planar packing, minus some boundary effects that can't be any larger than $O(\frac{R}{r})$.